# How to create a local zip file for Zip Deployment to Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

Let's say I have a directory 'foo' that contains my Azure Function Project, built in TypeScript. My structure is like that described in the [JavaScript documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#folder-structure) for Azure Function (The TypeScript folder structure is very similar to the JavaScript folder structure). I now want to create a zip file that I can publish to Azure using the [Zip Deployment mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push). How do I create the zip file manually and then publish it to Azure Functions?

***Note***: I bootstrapped the project using [Azure Function Core Tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools) and am developing in Visual Studio Code on macOS

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, you will need to build your project. In the case of TypeScript, that involves executing:

```
npm install
npm run build:production
```

Then, assuming you are working on a bash shell, you can manually create the zip file using the following command:

```
zip -r app.zip . --exclude @.funcignore --exclude .funcignore
```

This command tells `zip` to zip everything in the current directory except what is in .funcignore and the .funcignore file itself.

After this command completes, you can deploy to Azure using the following Azure CLI command:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g ${MY_RESOURCE_GROUP} -n ${MY_APP_NAME} --src app.zip
```

*MY_RESOURCE_GROUP* is the resource group in Azure you are publishing into and *MY_APP_NAME* is the name of your app. (Note: You will have to login to Azure using the CLI first).

Comment: This just saved me a ton of time. Thank you!